# Mixing Workflow with Experience Manager (Session Preview)

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, workflow

Has anybody worked together with the Session Preview of Experience Manager and workflow?

I think there is a problem of saving automatically the modified components in the experience manager whenever they are changed, because if there is a workflow associated with the schema of the component, then the componente as it is saved, enters the workflow.

Then the contents of the component may be assigned to another profile in the workflow, when it is intended that the modifications of the component remained local by the session preview.

Is there a way of working with workflow and session preview, or is it needed to avoid the session preview in the experience manager?

And therefore, is it useful and usual to work with the experience manager with the session preview disabled?

Answer (score 5):

In Experience Manager, when changing a Component based on a Schema that has a Workflow process associated to it, the component enters Workflow indeed, but in my case the current user is assigned correctly to the first workflow activity, and you can perform several changes in the content of the component before eventually finishing your activity. Also, if I open the same page in a different browser and authenticate as another user, I can click Update Preview but do not see the change performed by the other user, since the workflow activity is not finished/approved yet. This looks like expected behavior to me.

When starting a review activity, you will need to click Update Preview to see the changes performed by the original creator. This is also expected behavior and works fine for me.
I am therefore able to work with workflow in Experience Manager, with Session Preview enabled.

However, I agree with you that once the component entered the first Workflow activity, the Cancel Editing button does not rollback the change and does not finish the workflow process to cancel it. This said, it happens with or without Session Preview disabled.
Is this what you are referring to?